# Maintaining two Xcode versions in parallel on a Mac

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4

Can we maintain two versions of Xcode (like Xcode 3.2 and Xcode 4) in parallel on a single Mac machine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes - this works fine - normally when you install Xcode 4 if you already have an older version of Xcode it gets moved to `/Developer-old` and the new Xcode 4 installation goes in `/Developer`. Many people such as myself do this so that they can have both Xcode 3.x and Xcode 4.x installed at the same time.

Comment: Hi Paul R, I had Xcode3.2.5 and now installed Xcode4.2 but after that I can't find Xcode3.2.5 in my system. Also there is no /Developer-old folder in my mac. Can you please help me out. I have wasted a lot of time in search of answer to the same question of mine. Please help me.

Comment: You just need to make sure that you install Xcode 4 in a different directory than any existing Xcode 3 installation. Typically you would rename your old Xcode 3 /Developer directory to /Developer-old and then install Xcode 4 in /Developer. Some versions of the Xcode 4 installer offer to do this for you, but it is quite easy to do manually. If you have lost Xcode 3 then just re-install it.

Comment: works like a charm! **For Xcode 4 and 5 on OSX 10.8.5 you need to rename ~/Library/Developer (this is the default install directory)